# How to subtract from column in Dataframe based on conditions from other columns in row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary set up like the example below and I am trying to subtract values from a column in a DataFrame if the key in the row matches a value in the dictionary and the string column in that row is yes.

```
dic = {1:2300,
       2:3000,
       56:572
       37:2930}
```

```
df = key   string   value
     1     yes      5000
     4     yes      2000
     56    no       1000
     56    yes      6000
     14    yes      3000
```

I would want the function to subtract the dictionary value from the value column ONLY if the key exists in the dictionary and the string==yes. The resulting Dataframe would look like the following:

```
after = key   string   value
        1     yes      2700
        4     yes      2000
        56    no       1000
        56    yes      5428
        14    yes      3000
```

I tried writing a loop going through each row of the Dataframe and subtracting the df['value'] by dic[row] if the key and string value matched, but it wasn't working after trying to tweak multiple things.

```
for row in df:
    if dic.get(row['key'],0)!=0 and row['string']=='yes':
        row['value']=row['value']-dic[row['key']]
```

This code didn't work and just returned "TypeError: string indices must be integers". What should I change to correct it?

Comment: Please provide the entire error message. It would also be good to have your data in a more convenient format. Have you done any research, read the Pandas docs? As an aside, why use `"yes"`/`"no"` instead of proper boolean values?

Answer (score 2):

There are pandas methods for this, try to avoid using loops unnecessarily  that slow down and dirty the code. We could use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df['string'].eq('yes'),'value']=(df['value'].sub(df['key'].map(dic))
                                                   .fillna(df['value']))

   key string   value
0    1    yes  2700.0
1    4    yes  2000.0
2   56     no  1000.0
3   56    yes  5428.0
4   14    yes  3000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#sample dataframe
d = {'key': [1,4,56,56,14], 'string': ['yes','yes','no','yes','yes'], 'value': [5000, 2000, 1000, 6000,3000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
#dictionary
dic = {1:2300,
       2:3000,
       56:572,
       37:2930}

#iterating through dataframe
for i, row in df.iterrows():
  #assigning values
  key = df.loc[i,'key']
  string = df.loc[i,'string']
  value = df.loc[i,'value']
  #if key in dictionary and string == yes, get value from dictionary by key and calculate the result
  if key in dic.keys() and string == 'yes':
    dicValue = dic[key]
    result = value - dicValue
    print(result)
```

Comment: see `pd.read_clipboard` in order to copy and work with dataframe. In another hands use loops here is inefficient